# Sum and count a stream of numbers coming from a generator expression

Tags: python

I can sum a stream of numbers coming from a generator expression

```
education = '0 1 0 0 0'.split()
salary = [int(s) for s in '50 120 0 40 60'.split()] # 0 for missing data
# compute the sum of known low education salaries, aka les
total_les = sum(s for e, s in zip(education, salary) if e=='0' and s>0)
```

now I'd like to compute the mean of the known salaries, in my example it's `150/3` …

I could get a list of low education salaries

```
 list_of_les = [s for e, s in zip(education, salary) if e=='0' and s>0]
 mean_les = sum(list_of_les)/len(list_of_les)
```

or I could count again my stream

```
 count = sum(1 for e, s in zip(education, salary) if e=='0' and s>0)
```

but, for the sake of discussion, let's say that the length of the stream is really large   and I don't want an unneeded gigantic list and that the stream is not replicable (not really my example…).

  *Is it possible to sum and count the stream at the same time?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reduce` you can basically do arbitrary aggregations, even multiples at once. The following calculates the sum and count at the same time:

```
import functools
data = [1, 3, 5, 6, 2]
s, c = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: [a[0] + b, a[1] + 1], data, [0,0]) 
# outputs 17, 5
```

Comment: Hi, good answer +1, thank you very much. Your import is from the standard library so it's fine for me but I'll wait and see if there is a no import answer…

Comment: @gboffi fine with me - note that the `reduce` itself is pretty straight-forward, it is basically a for-loop over the elements and applying the lambda over and over again.

Comment: What are `lis` and `data` and how do they relate to `education` and `salary`?

Comment: @KellyBundy `lis` was a messed up variable name, should have been `data`. And they do not relate to both variables from the question but answer the general question *"Is it possible to sum and count the stream at the same time?"*. I feel like OP can transfer the knowledge if neccessary.

Comment: That's what I thought, I was compiling solutions for my answer's test and didn't want to fix it in an unintended way. Not sure whether I should include yours now, since you chose to use a list, and with list it'd look worse than it would with a generator.

Comment: @luk2302 _"I feel like OP can transfer the knowledge if necessary"_ … :-)

Comment: Included it in my [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69833030/12671057) where I give all solutions just a stream. Making the pairs tuples instead of lists took a bit less memory and time.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter it with a generator expression instead of turning it into a list; all you need to do is use `()` instead of `[]` -- this will process it in a "streaming" fashion instead of creating the whole thing in memory:

```
low_edu = (s for e, s in zip(education, salary) if e=='0' and s>0)
```

Then just add up the total and count together:

```
total, count = 0, 0
for salary in low_edu:
    total += salary
    count += 1
```

You could mash this into another generator expression with `functools.reduce` but it reads a lot cleaner with a simple loop imo.

Comment: I just realized that the `reduce` method actually is just that, a normal for loop, nothing complicated or magic :D

Comment: @luk2302 but don't underestimate the fascination of one-liners…

Comment: I am certainly guilty of that.

Comment: Positive appreciation for your least astonishment solution!

Comment: @gboffi thanks! I try to avoid the siren call of complicated one-liners in anything somebody else will have to read. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd just use a simple loop *without* the generator expression.

```
total = count = 0
for e, s in zip(education, salary):
    if e == '0' and s > 0:
        total += s
        count += 1
mean = total / count
```

Though if you already only have the iterator of preprocessed values, then tzaman's would be my choice. Then again, you're considering to *"count again my stream"*, so apparently you *are* in control of the code so *could* do it without the generator.

Measuring memory usage and runtime of the various working solutions for larger input (100,000 elements):

```
            original  406.72 KB   7.0 ms  result = 24.990380884305115
         Kelly_Bundy    0.24 KB  10.1 ms  result = 24.990380884305115
              tzaman    0.40 KB  11.6 ms  result = 24.990380884305115
         user2390182 6155.90 KB  16.0 ms  result = 24.990380884305115
 alparslan_mimaroğlu  441.23 KB  21.4 ms  result = 24.990380884305115
         user1740577  406.86 KB   7.2 ms  result = 24.990380884305115
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVVJbtswFN37FL@LwJRLOJKdwKkBZZFtjxAYAiNTCVEOAkkhcS7Ty/ReLidZcmqhbbSR@Ce@9ye1B/ui5Pqu1cdjo5UATeTevZholbZQvyhWUzMLKmaptkpx02stpbP@U5OaCsK5qntR08k6mEdvywRltnfVtKXEzmZ72oDS7JlJwhHddzWxTEkMhnCiD9l2Bu7hzNhKNRWnBkp4NNAoDdQZAZPwztoLjsAaoGU5z@fgCIG5z3chlKa20xJMJ9AoanbNqTwTRGTfKeeH6qGT@8MkOKss4Q5WrTpp3TsP0r8jjN7@8VChLOEEFu4hH9TDJV9LMGfieKcTF2Ny0fg6aiMR@04EkdMJVq@V0zn06HPJzYZU4CETeJSM6OpjpssGggO5YDP7b3adoXq1/pYXd6tJisbhcpgEaZErPg7MFgg5cZF9jnKWnXWUhxThEN4SbTiRlWCCaPXrJ@8mcf2Q6lWahIwT8bQn8LaFt8diBxgaxt3Qncnz3bhXgt2XkOvLwBNKFO8pcLpwlUHpxjeJMayyj@ORHDLHyx@LkKTKZ6iPMCS/2Nzkt5vNdPI74aZKOpaJiYUt@Dogm2Hws2cTToN9lZI9@uyoT1VGECZRwuTRFDksFnAbzqfAfpbj2kOPLiiGeTHfubyVMkGMnTxYuZX5TNFtniWjYBWmjhqLwhp0YUcDP1qWS2OJtig76TQ1HffT0/shv3YH2u6SIOjLe3IUVKgAaxz9mdoqnPdV1KPMNcwEENWOcPh17bvSJSzu6tSE238FhkF24onqshiBbDWTFs2vVrmZw9Up1LKqJBG0qvDZegOYX22WK7eHH8Cbo8TxGgq6zv60vVkWrsYm2gYCi8uWfZJdceNnKtqpxWNJ16OaeVUP11v0Py08/kngtGjxeCXhiwsBjwfnw7I/a5sPuXNIYxcfj78B)):

```
from random import choices
from itertools import tee
import tracemalloc
import functools
from timeit import repeat

def original(education, salary):
    list_of_les = [s for e, s in zip(education, salary) if e=='0' and s>0]
    return sum(list_of_les)/len(list_of_les)

def Kelly_Bundy(education, salary):
    total = count = 0
    for e, s in zip(education, salary):
        if e == '0' and s > 0:
            total += s
            count += 1
    return total / count

def tzaman(education, salary):
    low_edu = (s for e, s in zip(education, salary) if e=='0' and s>0)
    total, count = 0, 0
    for salary in low_edu:
        total += salary
        count += 1
    return total / count

def user2390182(education, salary):
    s, c = map(sum, zip(*((s, 1) for e, s in zip(education, salary) if e=='0' and s>0)))
    return s / c

def alparslan_mimaroğlu(education, salary):
    knowns = map(lambda x: x[1] , filter(lambda x: x[0] == '0' and x[1] != 0, zip(education, salary)))
    (knowns1, knowns2) =tee(knowns, 2)
    return sum(knowns1) / sum(1 for _ in knowns2)

def user1740577(education, salary):
    sum_len = lambda t : (sum(t), len(t))
    s,c = sum_len([s for e, s in zip(education, salary) if e=='0' and s>0])
    return s / c

def main():
    n = 10 ** 5
    education = choices(['0', '1'], k=n)
    salary = choices(range(50), k=n)

    def test(function):
        tracemalloc.start()
        result = function(iter(education), iter(salary))
        memory = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()[1]
        tracemalloc.stop()
        time = min(repeat(lambda: function(iter(education), iter(salary)), number=1))
        print('%20s' % function.__name__,
              '%7.2f KB ' % (memory / 1e3),
              '%4.1f ms ' % (time * 1e3),
              'result =', result)

    for _ in range(3):
        for function in original, Kelly_Bundy, tzaman, user2390182, alparslan_mimaroğlu, user1740577:
            test(function)
        print()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @luk2302's approach, but not using `reduce`, but simple back-n-forth transpositioning:

```
s, c = map(sum, zip(*((s, 1) for e, s in zip(education, salary) if e=='0' and s>0)))
```

Comment: Great answer as well, thank you. I appreciate the pure Python approach (until they move `map` to `functools`, that is;-)

Comment: @gboffi How is it great when you're worried about memory usage of your list and it takes [way more memory](https://tio.run/##nZJNasMwEIX3PsVsgqVgUjuGkBbSRfc9QQhC2ONEoD8keZFe3pUlJ00h3VS7mTea7/Ekew0Xo9u9ddM0OKNABHTBGOlBKGtcAIcWeSiWKjjeoeJSmq4oehzAOHEWmkuC/djxIIyuwHPJ3ZW@FRCPFD4wMzCJHg5w9DAYBxiHQGj4EvbJRRAD4OFQ1iVw3YN/r08ZNnp02/a1bvbbP3m@gi6CFLfEj6pKiDUhsd3Qf7EppZke0AcyjLqbLyw0HVFNDes17FJ9Xxj7OTkSV1WgaTaXID9ac1cegt34wF0guX/jPbGadIXKpI2PC84YWKp7lnVCj83pCcfYBWOd0NHqqu3h8wNKWAFZNr9Agzta3Y1sGNNcIWMxlTlONmfpuD4jaZdQ5vZtfFZvf6R6fMA8miz9ynWavgE)?

Comment: @KellyBundy I said that I _pretend_ to worry about memory for the sake of the discussion …

Answer (score 0):

Four memory-efficient ways if you do already have a preprocessed "stream", not the two sources:

Walrus:

```
def mean(stream):
    count = 0
    total = sum(x for x in stream if (count := count + 1))
    return total / count
```

Advancing an `itertools.count` in parallel:

```
def mean(stream):
    ctr = count()
    total = sum(x for x, _ in zip(stream, ctr))
    return total / next(ctr)
```

Or with an `itemgetter`:

```
def mean(stream):
    ctr = count()
    total = sum(map(itemgetter(0), zip(stream, ctr)))
    return total / next(ctr)
```

With `enumerate`:

```
def mean(stream):
    total = 0
    for count, x in enumerate(stream, 1):
        total += x
    return total / count
```

Demo:

```
from itertools import count
from operator import itemgetter

def mean1(stream):
    count = 0
    total = sum(x for x in stream if (count := count + 1))
    return total / count

def mean2(stream):
    ctr = count()
    total = sum(x for x, _ in zip(stream, ctr))
    return total / next(ctr)

def mean3(stream):
    ctr = count()
    total = sum(map(itemgetter(0), zip(stream, ctr)))
    return total / next(ctr)

def mean4(stream):
    total = 0
    for count, x in enumerate(stream, 1):
        total += x
    return total / count

for func in mean1, mean2, mean3, mean4:
    education = '0 1 0 0 0'.split()
    salary = [int(s) for s in '50 120 0 40 60'.split()] # 0 for missing data
    stream = (s for e, s in zip(education, salary) if e=='0' and s>0)
    print(func(stream))
```

Output:

```
50.0
50.0
50.0
50.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how Python itself does it, for its [statistics.fmean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.fmean). See the part `Handle iterators that do not define __len__()`:

```
def fmean(data):
    """Convert data to floats and compute the arithmetic mean.
    This runs faster than the mean() function and it always returns a float.
    If the input dataset is empty, it raises a StatisticsError.
    >>> fmean([3.5, 4.0, 5.25])
    4.25
    """
    try:
        n = len(data)
    except TypeError:
        # Handle iterators that do not define __len__().
        n = 0
        def count(iterable):
            nonlocal n
            for n, x in enumerate(iterable, start=1):
                yield x
        total = fsum(count(data))
    else:
        total = fsum(data)
    try:
        return total / n
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        raise StatisticsError('fmean requires at least one data point') from None
```

I btw measured the memory usage of `statistics.fmean` and it took very little. So in case you have a huge stream and just want the mean, this function might be good.

Answer (score 0):

More direct comparison of more solutions, giving each a stream of 100,000 numbers without the backstory data, and somewhat unifying their code for better comparison.

```
           with_list   900.16 KB   1.0 ms  result = 49.66821
          with_tuple   800.10 KB   1.1 ms  result = 49.66821
           with_loop     0.08 KB   8.1 ms  result = 49.66821
      with_transpose 12688.18 KB  22.7 ms  result = 49.66821
            with_tee   898.95 KB   5.5 ms  result = 49.66821
         with_reduce     0.30 KB  21.8 ms  result = 49.66821
       with_reduce_2     0.25 KB  19.9 ms  result = 49.66821
              walrus     0.29 KB   8.4 ms  result = 49.66821
   itertools_count_1     0.36 KB   7.3 ms  result = 49.66821
   itertools_count_2     0.27 KB   6.6 ms  result = 49.66821
    with_enumerate_1     0.15 KB   7.6 ms  result = 49.66821
    with_enumerate_2     0.45 KB   6.9 ms  result = 49.66821
     statistics_mean   900.87 KB  50.8 ms  result = 49.66821
    statistics_fmean     0.64 KB   7.8 ms  result = 49.66821
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVbBjqMwDL33K3wZNXSiDrS70qgSl73uJ1QVYmmYiZYkKARtZ3@@65AAgdKdDoeW2I79/GI71B/mXcn9a62v11IrATqXZ/zjolbaQPGueMGaVafihmmjVNX0WsMYhUK10qx6ic4LJvKqUoXbU7aymOzR7NwWzCkNF4ybUVOzfPDUmNzwxvDCB1c107lRurdGMOKNGYS0Wp1ZCX@4ec8q3EEao1kuosMK8NHMtFpC0wpSNQYOKYQ2EbxAxaRVRYEb09YVu@vH1JX1MzHqHaEudFQpVU/9GGXyClLHGv7HnbTEvC7A0X9n60xH8@cULoPI7URREgJzhi/@NIJU8DybWjVsAQYdUIgcYbaCwl9ekw0hFwpJNEcVRdFDEdksFjcJxZ8dxgl0c1bRypJoX5MucmYj47aQT1c8/03Fm1S5@HXOwRQULgc4muIYn@AZMDF8TexrcqI@MQrHmEJ8eig95z/bfR0EWQIRjSCIBfE5x3ml22YafVpMfYlZKi/zQwReAnH2h74KLYzPwg69n3XCLJkhMLovahLdQ0Hdmdoa63PGfcuhJbsYYrXL4XdfCW@rexwXJI7oLYZHQHTnz2Qr7CRicwr6iGNHd3ioY3/YNoRNortt/kkJjhBmNMghvLX1dIxRpJI4l9GlHEQWprwLEWewNmkI1D4fnFXnKVLLsg9nm1g6sOMIzwTL5fJAHWy2oc2Ng/IRD@XURXf3cCUbpOXYbRkuCTouuzkerO3MDtX9AA1lLFy5Zr8RZDsv6hqW@lE466Jl8S5wFtTbotTbzri@EZZOenLEipxLEhRNEsNmA9/duhW/mLac@cufIANvjCSxbZzfqURm@xIzDO/SnuagTPysSbvMiPcYjeU@fiVsuxojo06zpq3sMOvdTi4M@wgmlP6wt0ngBns769bnzOlJhBN2dSck3soBGvwKsXcgUuI@QfzcPowQJmkgC@41xXvN7Uj3dnAPHmvNsRXWT7u4WcPT4GabZTIXLMvopJ8A1k@v210JP3@ANSc@wRdI2D66tf22TfAEG2fbgd8sW/ZUrqln1UMcbld3sPvg4Kyqh2sthhaajoDpuc/yxiiuvq7Xfw)):

```
from random import choices
from itertools import tee, count
import tracemalloc
from functools import reduce
from timeit import repeat
import statistics
from operator import itemgetter

def with_list(stream):
    return sum(lst := list(stream)) / len(lst)

def with_tuple(stream):
    return sum(tpl := tuple(stream)) / len(tpl)

def with_loop(stream):
    total = count = 0
    for x in stream:
        total += x
        count += 1
    return total / count

def with_transpose(stream):
    total, count = map(sum, zip(*((x, 1) for x in stream)))
    return total / count

def with_tee(stream):
    it1, it2 = tee(stream)
    return sum(it1) / sum(1 for _ in it2)

def with_reduce(stream):
    total, count = reduce(lambda tc, x: [tc[0] + x, tc[1] + 1], stream, [0, 0])
    return total / count

def with_reduce_2(stream):
    total, count = reduce(lambda tc, x: (tc[0] + x, tc[1] + 1), stream, (0, 0))
    return total / count

def walrus(stream):
    count = 0
    total = sum(x for x in stream if (count := count + 1))
    return total / count

def itertools_count_1(stream):
    ctr = count()
    total = sum(x for x, _ in zip(stream, ctr))
    return total / next(ctr)

def itertools_count_2(stream):
    ctr = count()
    total = sum(map(itemgetter(0), zip(stream, ctr)))
    return total / next(ctr)

def with_enumerate_1(stream):
    total = 0
    for count, x in enumerate(stream, 1):
        total += x
    return total / count

def with_enumerate_2(stream):
    n = 0
    def count():
        nonlocal n
        for n, x in enumerate(stream, start=1):
            yield x
    return sum(count()) / n

def statistics_mean(stream):
    return statistics.mean(stream)

def statistics_fmean(stream):
    return statistics.fmean(stream)

functions = [
    with_list,
    with_tuple,
    with_loop,
    with_transpose,
    with_tee,
    with_reduce,
    with_reduce_2,
    walrus,
    itertools_count_1,
    itertools_count_2,
    with_enumerate_1,
    with_enumerate_2,
    statistics_mean,
    statistics_fmean,
]

def main():
    n = 10 ** 5
    numbers = choices(range(100), k=n)

    def test(function):
        stream = iter(numbers)
        tracemalloc.start()
        result = function(stream)
        memory = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()[1]

        tracemalloc.stop()
        time = min(repeat(lambda: function(iter(numbers)), number=1, repeat=30))

        print('%20s' % function.__name__,
              '%8.2f KB ' % (memory / 1e3),
              '%4.1f ms ' % (time * 1e3),
              'result =', result)

    for _ in range(3):
        for function in functions:
            test(function)
        print()

main()
```